# Each time selects same color instead of random in color guessing game javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote down the code for color guessing javascript code. but the problem is each time i run this code, it selects same color instead of selecting random color. I am wondering if someone help me out in this. I will be very thankful!

```
<head>
    <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Wajeb Saab">
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">

    <script>
        var target_color;
        var target_index;
        var guessed_color;
        var guesses = 0;
        var color = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "crimson", "darkorange", "olive", "silver", "steelblue", "tomato", "green"];
        var finished = false;

        function do_game()
        {
            color.sort();
            var random_number = Math.random() * (color.length-1);
            target_index = Math.floor(random_number);
            target_color = color[target_index];
            alert("Hint: The target color is " + target_color);

            var text = "I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + color.join(", ")
                        + "\n\n What color am I thinking of?";

            while(!finished)
            {
                guessed_color = prompt(text);
                guesses++;
                finished = check_guess();
            }

            myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                myBody.style.background = target_color;
        }

        function check_guess()
        {
            if(color.indexOf(guessed_color) < 0) // check if guessed color is not included in array
            {
                alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color.\n\n" + "Please try again.");
                return false;
            }
            else if(guessed_color > target_color)
            {
                alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\n" + "Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine.\n\n"
                      + "Please try again.");
                return false;
            }
            else if(guessed_color < target_color)
            {
                alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\n" + "Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine.\n\n"
                      + "Please try again.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {

                alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\n" + "It took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game.\n\n"
                      + "You can see the color in the background.");
                return true;
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please Help, i would be thankful :)

Comment: It is working fine....

Comment: Feel free to plagiarise, but at least change the author :)
`<meta name="author" content="Wajeb Saab">`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to reset your guessed_color and target_color when returning true in the check_guesses() function, then you need to set finished = false as the first line in your do_game() function. Like so...

```
function do_game() {
    finished = false;
    color.sort();
    var random_number = Math.random() * (color.length - 1);
    target_index = Math.floor(random_number);
    console.log(target_index);
    target_color = color[target_index];
    var text = "I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + color.join(", ") + "\n\n What color an I thinking of?";
    while(!finished) {
        guessed_color = prompt(text);
        guesses++;
        finished = check_guesses();
    }
}

function check_guesses() {
    if(color.indexOf(guessed_color) < 0) {
        console.log("Sorry I don't know what color that is");
        return false;
    } else if(guessed_color > target_color) {
        console.log("Incorrect!\n\n Your color is Alphabetically higher than mine");
        return false;
    } else if(guessed_color < target_color) {
        console.log("Incorrect\n\n Your color is lower than mine");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("You WIN!");
        guessed_color = null;
        target_color = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

As of right now, you set the color, then check it, but without resetting it when you return true, the game ends, the color is set, so next time you run it it will be the same color.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but my problem solved by applying this.

color=color.sort();